# Proper use of CFStringTokenizerCreate with ARC?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a piece of code that the ARC converter turned into this...

```
// firstRange is a NSRange obviously
// test is an NSString * passed in as parameter to the method
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(firstRange.location, (lastRange.location - firstRange.location) + lastRange.length);
NSString *sentence = [text substringWithRange:range];
// OK, now chop it up with the better parser
CFRange allTextRange = CFRangeMake(0, [sentence length]);
CFLocaleRef locale = CFLocaleCopyCurrent();
CFStringTokenizerRef tokenizer = CFStringTokenizerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
  (__bridge CFStringRef) sentence,
  allTextRange,
  kCFStringTokenizerUnitWord,
  locale);
```

I call this A LOT and I suspect that it leaks somehow. Is that CFStringTokenizerCreate call kosher? I am especially suspicious of the __bridge call. Do I create an intermediate that I have to manually release or some such evil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `CFRelease` the `tokenizer` and `locale` or else they will leak.

This falls under  [Core Foundation Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-CJBEJBHH) and has nothing to do with ARC.

The `__bridge` cast tells ARC that no ownership transfer is done for `sentence` in `CFStringTokenizerCreate` call. So that is Ok.

You can test for memory leaks with Xcode's static analyser and profiler.

Comment: Hmm, turns out that I do that, but your point is still valid. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `CFRelease(tokenizer);` when you are done using the tokenizer. See [Ownership Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html). You should call `CFRelease(locale);` too.

Your `__bridge sentence` syntax is correct. I must say that Xcode is correct about `__bridge` and `__bridge_transfer` most of the time. In your case, you are passing a reference of NSObject for use with CF. You have no intention to transfer the ownership to CF because you think ARC is great at managing NSObjects. So when `CFStringTokenizerCreate` is done using `sentence`, it won't do anything to free it up. ARC will then free up `sentence`.

On the other hand, if you changed it to `__bridge_transfer`, you are telling ARC that you are transferring the ownership to CF. Therefore, when you are done, ARC won't free up `sentence`. You must call `CFRelease(sentence);` to free it up, which is not a desired behavior.

Comment: I made the same mistake above, but it's actually backwards.  __bridge_transfer transfers ownership INTO an ARC object, and __bridge_retained transfers ownership into a CF object.

Answer (score 0):

My gut tells me that it should be __bridge_transfer instead of bridge since you are calling create (unless there is a CFRelease call later).  I also think the locale needs to be released since it is a copy.

**EDIT** Oops ignore me, I read it wrong (was using a phone)

Answer (score 0):

For any Swift users reading this thread: the `CFRelease()` function does not seem to have been carried on into the Swift language, as Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed (according to a compiler warning I'm seeing in Swift 3.0.2), so that's one less thing to think about.